# Require elements based on the value of another element

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there a way to create conditional requirement based on the value of an another element in XSD?

This is the XML input​, so if `mT` enum value is `Prm` then elements `mTT`, `MTV` and `mTR` are required:

```
<mT>Prm</mT>
<mTT>H</mTT>
<mTV>25</mTV>
<mTR>Re</mTR>
```

The schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
    <xs:complexType name="ciType">
      <xs:all>
       <xs:element name="mT">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="Cm"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Com"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Prm"/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </element>
        <xs:element name="mTV">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="mTR">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="N-r"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="Re"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="mTT">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="D"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="H"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="W"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="Y"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
```

​       
    ​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael Kay [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29625484/290085), XSD 1.0 cannot express such a constraint, but XSD 1.1 assertions can.  Here is an `xs:assertion` to meet your requirements:

```
<xs:assert test="(mT != 'Prm' or (mTV and mTR and mTT))"/>
```

And here is the assertion in the context of your `ciType` declaration within a complete XSD 1.1:

### XSD 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="r" type="ciType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="ciType">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="mT">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Cm"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Com"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Prm"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="mTV"  minOccurs="0">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="mTR" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="N-r"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Re"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="mTT" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="D"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="H"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="W"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Y"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:all>
    <xs:assert test="(mT != 'Prm' or (mTV and mTR and mTT))"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you very much kjhughes and Michael Kay. I have downloaded Altova XML Spy, added the new schema attributes and the assertion tag, and everything is valid! But it didn't solve my problem. If I send a value to <mt>Cm</mT> in my xml file, and leave mTV, mTR and MTT out, I get an error when validating the xml file, telling me these elements are missing. <mT>Cm</mT>
<!--<mTT>H</mTT>
<mTV>25</mTV>
<mTR>Re</mTR>-->

Comment: @SuperHannaR: Sorry, there should have been a `minOccurs="0"` on `mTV`, `mTR`, and `mTT` to allow their requiredness to be governed solely by the assertion.  I've fixed the XSD for you in the answer.  **Note**: You must have a single root element in your XML document for it to be well-formed.  I've called that `r` in the above XSD.

Comment: thank you very much! so simple, why didn't I came up with that earlier :-)! You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do that. You could instead convert the enumeration into elements:

```
<Prm>
  <mTT>H</mTT>
  <mTV>25</mTV>
  <mTR>Re</mTR>
</Prm>
```

```
<xs:complexType name="ciType">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="Cm" type="ciTypeCm"/>
    <xs:element name="Com" type="ciTypeCom"/>
    <xs:element name="Prm" type="ciTypePrm"/>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ciTypePrm">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="mTV">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
          <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="mTR">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="N-r"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="Re"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="mTT">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="D"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="H"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="W"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="Y"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Thank you Markus, I appreciate your answer! The thing is that if I change the element name, this means that I need to change it in the code as well.  You see the enumerations values are values from a drop down list in a website, if I choose Prm value then fields mTT, mTR and mTV appear and are required to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in XSD 1.0. You can do it in XSD 1.1 using assertions.

Comment: Thank you Michael for you answer, I tried that to, but each time I got Unable to parse schema, I use Notepas++ to validate my xml against my schema. 
<xs:element name="mT" >
 <xs:alt cond="./@mT='Prm'" type="mTV"/>
 <xs:alt cond="./@mT='Prm'" type="mTR"/>
 <xs:alt cond="./@mT='Prm'" type="mTT"/>
</xs:element>

Comment: How do you do that based on enumeration value?

Comment: If you mean Nodepad++, then it does not support XSD 1.1. There are currently three XSD 1.1 processors I know of: Saxon, Xerces, and Altova.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I had no idea that Notepad++ supports only xsd 1.0. I did install Altova and followed kjhughes instructions, but it didn't solve my problem where if I mT != Prm then mTT, mTV, mTR are not required and vice verse.